# Group in grouped barplot in pyplot with different group sizes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to create a grouped bar plot with different group sizes like shown below.

[image: Grouped bar plot how it sholud be]

I have a code which groups the bars but because not every group has the same number of samples (Runs) empty samples are shown.

[image: Grouped bar plot with empty samples]

Is it possible to check the size of the groups that no samples (Runs) without data are shown?

Here the corresponding code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import transforms
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Machine Number':  ['Machine 1', 'Machine 1', 'Machine 2','Machine 3','Machine 4','Machine 4'],
             'Experiment': ['Run 1','Run 2','Run 1', 'Run 1','Run 1','Run 2'],
             'Result': [10,32,71, 11,13,7]
             })
machines = df_2['Machine Number'].unique()
experiments = df_2['Experiment'].unique()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax = sns.barplot(x='Machine Number', y='Result', hue='Experiment', palette='Reds', data=df_2, ax=ax)

experiment_pos = np.sort( [p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2  for p in ax.patches])

ax.set_xticks(experiment_pos)
ax.set_xticklabels(np.tile(experiments, len(machines)), rotation=30)
ax.get_legend().remove()
ax.set_xlabel('') # remove default xlabel


machine_pos = experiment_pos.reshape(-1, len(experiments)).mean(axis=1)
trans = transforms.blended_transform_factory(ax.transData, ax.transAxes)

for pos, machine in zip(machine_pos, machines):
    ax.text(pos, -0.25,  machine, transform=trans, ha='center', va='bottom', color='steelblue', fontsize=14)
for pos in (machine_pos[:-1] + machine_pos[1:]) / 2:
    ax.axvline(pos, 0, -0.25, color='steelblue', ls=':' , clip_on=False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

st.pyplot(fig)
```

Comment: In this case, you get the height of each and null is a group with no height. You can get it with the following code. `for i in range(len(ax.containers)):for k in ax.containers[i]:        h = k.get_height();        print(h)`

Comment: @r-beginners thanks for the quick reply. With your code I get the two Bar containers (Run1 and Run2) with 4 artists each and the corresponding values of the bars. With that I can identify the bars with nan values. I do not know how I can use that in my code that only bars with a value are shownn and the formatting for the legends and the distance between the bars is right. Do you have an idea and could you help to implement it in my code above?

Comment: What do you want to do next, I don't think you can delete a group of null values.

Comment: I think the problem is when I create the dataframes for the bar plots to set up the bars, legends and groups. I combine all machine numbers and all runs but there are no values for some combinations (for example machine 3 Run 2). I would like to set up and plot the bars only for the combinations which have values that no empty bars are shown. For example when I add Run 7 to machine 4 that only in the group of machine 4 the bar run 7 is shown and not in all machine groups.  I think you are right that I can't delete afterwards.

Comment: I don't see why there are no values for machine 2 and machine 3 on the first graph; the second graph, with run2 on the x-axis, gives me an idea why. It is correct as a visualization.

Comment: The reason is that I have several machines and do a lot of experiments with every machine but the run number (experiment number) of each machine do not match because not every experiment is relevant for this evaluation. For this evaluation for machine 1 both runs are relevant and for machine 2 only the first one. If I have one machine with  for examle 7 relevant runs and all other have only one relevant run the chart is getting confusing and big because all machines show 7 runs

Comment: Ultimately, it comes down to what you prioritize and what you give up. For example, your goal might be achieved by concatenating `matplotlib` subplots with zero horizontal spacing. (No guarantees, though.)